# How to solve error "This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in" in Eclipse Mars?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new to Android programming. I want to stick with Eclipse IDE for developing Android apps as I am comfortable with it. But when I tried to setup Eclipse Mars to work with Android Marshmallow I got following error shown in Eclipse

> "This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in".

If it is not possible to stick to Marshmallow then provide suggestions so that it is possible to work with Lollipop.

I am using

1. Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)
Build id: 20150621-1200

2. JDK 1.8.0_73

Android SDK Installed on my computer:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOWIb.png]

Installed ADT components for Eclipse:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7Ym7.png]

Comment: You really should and actually kind of have to switch to Android Studio. Eclipse is so terrible, you are really going to love Android Studio. Any time you spend to get Eclipse working is just going to be wasted since it is not really supported anymore for Android development. Android Studio is the official IDE.

Comment: I also think your best option is to switch to Android Studio. This is not so much because Eclipse is not good but because it is no longer supported for Android development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse Mars will work fine with Android Marshmallow on ADT 23.0.7 (the last released version as far as I know). Check out [this page](http://androidtoolsofflinedownload.blogspot.ca/p/blog-page_3.html) to find the released ADT versions available for download.

Please note that the layout engine will not work right, so you also need to download a Lollipop SDK so you can use it's layout engine with Marshmallow's build tools.

I can only expect development with Eclipse to get harder in the future. But for now, this should keep you going.

I don't know if API 24 or newer work properly with the SDK. You can check out this link for someone's private project based on an ADT beta release that claims to work with Android N:

https://github.com/khaledev/ADT